# Parse binary data to ASCII string

Tags: python, ascii, bitstring

I need convert binary data to ASCII string.
This string was packed as 15 bytes.
For parsing other data in packet I use `bitstring` Python module. But I can't find functions for ASCII string unpack.

I get string data in binary format:

```
>> value = const_bit_stream.read(8*15)
>> str(value)
'0x383638323034303031353732383939'
```

How I can convert these bytes to ASCII string using `bitstring` or other tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use binascii to convert binary to ASCII.

```
binascii.b2a_uu(data)
```

where *data* is a variable with a length of 45 or less characters. The return value is the converted value.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html